# Same distribution with different probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with probability density function:
$$f_a(x)=\frac{1}{a}$$
With $0<x<a$. I must find the Moment-generating function of $Y = -(\ln X - \ln a)$.

After calculation I've found that $M_Y(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$. So no matter what is the value of $a$. For every $a$, Moment-generating function is independent from $a$. So every $Y$ with different values of $a$ have the same distribution? Even if their probability density functions are different? Or I've found the Moment-generating function wrong?
$$M_Y(t)=E(e^{t(-(\ln X - \ln a)})=a^t\int_{0}^{a}x^{-t}\frac{1}{a}dx=\frac{1}{1-t}$$
So for every $t\in (-1,1)$, we have $E(e^{tY})<\infty$ and so the Moment-generating function exists.

Comment: And what if t=1?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the distribution of $Y=f(X/a)$ for any $f$ will be independent of $a$.  This is because $X/a\sim U(0,1).$

Yours is the special case where $f(z)=-\log(z)$.

Comment: If I show that for every $a$ the Cumulative distribution function of Y is independent from $a$, did I show that they have the same distribution?

Comment: Yes. Also, MGFs and CDFs are equivalent ways to characterize distributions.

Comment: The CDF of $Y$ here is $1-\frac{1}{e^u}$. So it has Exponential distribution with parameter 1, right?

Comment: @Mina that is right